# How to get the data from Django form and store on different variable every time user submit

Tags: python, django

I have the following view in my `views.py`:

```
 def post(self,request):
     form = HomeForm(request.POST)
     if form.is_valid():
```

I want to get the data from the field named `post` and assign it to a different variable.

```
        text = form.cleaned_data['post']

        form = HomeForm()
        return render(request, self.template_name, {'form': form})
```

Comment: Please explain further what do you mean when you say that you want to save the value of the `post` field in different variables.

Comment: You can use model form and save your data in your database, https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/topics/forms/modelforms/

Comment: you are already saving your post data in a text variable, Please explain why you want to save the data in another variable

Comment: m making the health prediction system, for that I have designed some questions which the system will ask to the user, I want to give the user two buttons one for next and other for check, user can ask for the next question by clicking next and check the prediction by clicking submit, for this I want to save the data on different variables so system can ask different question by knowing user submitted one answer